# draggable() containment within 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is it possible to restrict `draggable()` within 2 divs?

```
$('#drg').draggable({
    containment: $('#divb') // how do I say $('#diva') & $('#divb')
});
```

Comment: Wrap a `$('#divc')` around `$('#diva')` and `$('#divb')`? and then `containment: $('#divc')`. Or give a class to your div elements and use a class selector then `containment: $('.theClassDivAandBhas')`

Comment: Build a jsfiddle so we can play around and test

Comment: actually the class "solution" won't work: (From documentation) Selector: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.